# Python Selenium Click on invisible element

Tags: python, selenium

**Solved** I forget to switch to a new tab when previous action generate a new tab. Thank you for Helping out and giving the attentions

I am trying to download an excel file from a website. However I am not enable to click on it since it is invisible.

1. I have check that the element is not located on a separate iframe.
2. The element is indeed invisible.
3. I try waiting for the element to become visible and all I get is the following error

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.down-btn')))
```

> "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: "
> WebDriverWait(driver,
> 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
> 'a.down-btn')))
>
> "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: "

4. I also tried the `driver.excute_script` method to make the element visible, but this results in the following error

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("a.down-btn").style.visibility="visible";')
```

> javascript error: Cannot read property 'style' of null
> driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("a.down-btn").click();')
> Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of null

The following is the part of the html

```
<li data-v-58fef44c="">
  <div data-v-58fef44c="" class="data-left">
    <div data-v-58fef44c="" class="text-1">TEXT</div> 
    <div data-v-58fef44c="" class="text-2">TEXT2</div> 
    <div data-v-58fef44c="" class="text-3">TEXT3</div>
  </div> 
  <div data-v-58fef44c="" class="data-btn">
    "
                TEXT4
    "
    <a data-v-58fef44c="" href="http:somthing.xls" class="down-btn">TEXT4</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Why am I getting this error message, and how do I click the button?

Comment: Can you provide the link from which you want to download the excel file?

Comment: Try `attribute = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.down-btn'))).get_attribute("href")`

Comment: If it's hidden try using driver.execute_script instead.

Comment: @Sashaank I am sry i can't because you will need to login in to get access to that page

Comment: @DilipMeghwal I have try yours, but it return a attribute error: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Comment: @arundeepchohan can you be more specific, because i have try:driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("a.down-btn").click();')

And i cannot get it work, it return Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Comment: it looks like a Vue app. Vue will only insert the markup to the page once that element/component is actually being called. before that, it just doesn't exists yet.